# I cant declare a very basic function

Tags: c

I tried to compile a function and declared it like this:

```
float value_max (float x1, float x2, float x3, float x4, float x5);
```

But I got this:

```
2lab9.c:11:2: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wpedantic]
  void value_max (float x1, float x2, float x3, float x4, float x5);
```

Help, thanks

Comment: Do you declare the function inside of another function?

Comment: Post actual code. It's hard to tell what you did here without seeing the code, but it looks like you prototyped the function one way and declared it another.

Comment: Post the code please. Is this declaration made on the top of code block?

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
float valor_maximo (float x1, float x2, float x3, float x4, float x5);

int main(void)
{
 float x1, x2, x3, x4, x5;

 printf("Insira os números: \n");
 scanf("%f %f %f %f %f", &x1, &x2, &x3, &x4, &x5);

 float valor_maximo (float x1, float x2, float x3, float x4, float x5);

 return 0;
}

float valor_maximo (float x1, float x2, float x3, float x4, float x5)
{
 float max;
 max=x1;

 if(max<x2)
  max=x2;
 if(max<x3)
  max=x3;
 if(max<x4)
  max=x4;
 if(max<x5)
  max=x5;

 printf("%f", max);

 return;
}

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though the compiler detects conflicting declarations. The first one in your posted code returns `float` while the second one returns `void`.

Make sure both are same.

It will be better to put the declaration in a header file and `#include` the header file wherever you need it.

Comment: Sorry but I'm kinda a newby in this stuff...

Are sugesting me to save the function in another file and #include it. Is that right?